# Scrollerbar bug on the tag page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the tag page, if one searches for a tag that just barely is bigger than displayed area, then scrollerbars are shown. This is not the case if the amount of results is clearly more than a screenful, or less. Horizontal scrollerbars appear as well.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, after rev 2012.6.6.2800.